Trying to create a PIN. Dialog box closes
I have a notebook with an updated Windows 11. The user couldn't remember her PIN. So I logged in with her account and deleted the PIN using Accounts -> Sign-in options.
I rebooted and then tried to create a new PIN. When one does this, you get a dialog box asking for your Microsoft account. While typing her email address--one of the sign in options--the dialog box closes before I complete typing it.
Online I see others have had the same or similar issue and it appears it might have something to do with a Ngc folder but the solutions all point to a path to that folder which does not exist on this system. That is, following C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft where, in this case, AppData does not exist and I cannot find Ngc.
I am not a Windows user so I'll need a little hand holding with any solutions.

Local account or a local account attached to a MS account? Account probably just needs to be reauthenticated

@Ramhound You may be onto it. I tried doing something last night and it won't let me log in because Outlook says there's been suspicious activity and they want to change her password. I was going to try that last night but she wasn't available.
